# Genre of "Meant To Be" by Arc North

Tags: identify-this-genre, electronic-music, similar-artists

What is the genre of the main tune in the foreground of Arc North's [Meant To Be](https://youtu.be/kSmMOsJmkfs), and who are other artists working in this style?

Answer (score 3):

The style of music used in this track is a *genericized* form of [House Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_music) that is quite prominent in pop music today.

The original House Music stye has been highly influential to a lot modern music, and has evolved to include a plethora of sub-genres, so identifying a specific sub-genre will be difficult.

[Deep House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_house) is one common sub-genre of House Music that seems to align with your reference track, primarily due to the relatively low BPM of ~105, but also due to the general sound of artists in that genre.

As for other artists working in this style, they are too numerous and broad to try listing. Search for Deep House music, and you'll likely find tracks that are appealing.

Answer (score 2):

Beatport labels this track as [electronica-downtempo](https://www.beatport.com/genre/electronica-downtempo/3). See the side bar using previous link for similar artists and tracks. Another answer suggested [Deep-House](https://www.beatport.com/genre/deep-house/12), though that genre usually has BPM's around 120, not 105.